# File structure on a backbone web application

Tags: backbone.js, namespaces, directory-structure, backbone-routing

I am working on a web application that runs through backbone and makes use of the router. On success of certain events I want to redirect users to a static success page.

What is a good naming convention to clearly separate routing url paths from a static pages such as my success page?

the routing object in my route backbone object looks like this:

```
App.MyRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":                     "index",
        "!/search/*search":     "search",
        "!/profile/*user":      "profile",
        "!/business/:id":       "business"

    }
});
```

Comment: `/static/success.html` or I'm very confused or I don't understand the problem here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking either. If the static page is not part of your backbone routing then don't include it. The user will be redirected to the static page normally because Backbone router will ignore it if it doesn't have a matching route.